# Text in a set comprehension

Tags: math-mode

What is the proper way to typeset this set comprehension that has a lot of words in it? Is `\textrm` with manual spaces really the only way?

```
$$D = (S,
       \{(a,b) \,|\, \exists s,x,y\in S^* \textrm{ and } 
                     i < j \textrm{ such that } 
                     w^i = sax \textrm{ and } w^j = sby\})$$
```

Comment: just `text{...}`. and instead of $$ is better to  use `\[ ... `\]` or `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}`.

Comment: I would use `\textnormal` rather than `\textrm` or `\text`, or may be define `\newcommand*\mathwords{\textnormal}` and use `\mathwords{ such that }`, etc. Also a macro `\given` rather than writing directly `\,|\,`. There are multiple questions in this site where a nice of `\set{ .. \given .. }` is in the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With that answer, I'm concentrating on the "that has a lot of words in it" part on the question. The solution that is often used is `\text{...}` with `$...$` snippets for the math parts inside of it, just as you would use in normal text mode. You example might then look like this:

```
\[
D = (S, \{(a,b) \mid \text{$\exists s,x,y\in S^*$ and $i < j$
                            such that $w^i = sax$ and $w^j = sby$}\})
\]
```

Comment: +1. The only thing I'd change is to replace `\,|\,` with `\mid`. (`\mid` is a relational operator and thus inserts thickspace, not thinspace, on either side of the vertical bar.)

Comment: @Mico `\mid` is indeed better, I added it to the answer

Comment: I'd say that `\mid` is not good in general as it cannot be scaled. It is fine in most cases, but annoying when you want it scaled.

Comment: @daleif - Note that I did *not* say that "`\mid` is good in general". I was merely pointing out that for the formula at hand, using `\mid` was better than `\,|\,`. (If there was need to resize the vertical bar, I would have provided a different suggestion...)

Comment: my point is just that, many people use these pages as a guide as what to do, thus taking for granted that an ad hoc solution is **the** solution.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to keep set descriptions as short as possible. That long description hides the main parts at the end, where the reader will have a hard time to end at.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Here is a possibility
\[
D = (S, \{(a,b) \mid w^i=sax, w^j=sby \text{ for some $s,x,y\in S^*$, $i < j$}\}
\]
but probably it is better if you describe the set in words.

For $w\in S$, define $T_{w}$ as the set of pairs $(a,b)\in S\times S$
such that there exist $s,x,y\in S^{*}$ and $i<j$ so that $w^i=sax$ and
$w^j=sby$. Set $D=(S,T_w)$; then ...

\end{document}
```

[image]